# Vue props passing in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I am trying to pass 2 parameters in prop from blade template but the `eventId` is always `undefined` in `Vue` template.

Here is my Controller Code

```
public function index(Request $request, $eventId)
{
    return view('backend.organiser.classes.index')
        ->withClasses(Classes::orderBy('order')->get())
        ->withEventId($eventId);
}
```

Following is my `index.blade.php` code

```
    <div class="row mb-4">
        <div class="col">
            <div>{{ $eventId }}</div>
            <example-component :classes="{{ $classes }}" :eventId="{{ $eventId }}"></example-component>
        </div><!--col-->
    </div><!--row-->
```

Following is my `ExampleComponent.vue` code

```
<script>

    export default {

        props:['classes','eventId'],

        mounted() {
            console.log(this.eventId)
        }
    }
</script>
```

I get the data in `classes` but `eventId` is always `undefined`

What am I doing wrong here??

Answer (score 7):

Hope this can help you

```
<example-component props-classes="{{ $classes }}" props-eventid="{{ $eventId }}"></example-component>
```

Component

```
export default {
     props:['propsClasses','propsEventid'],

     mounted() {
        console.log(this.propsEventid)
     }
}
```

Good luck!!!